# Define a function one() that prints the string

Tags: python

Define a function one() that prints the string "Question 1". Do NOT call the function. 
and the result should be 
TEST : one()
Result: Question 1

I have tried this code

```
def one():
   print ("Question 1")
```

but nothing happened

Comment: I am a bit confused by this question. Are you trying to get the result of the def one(): without calling it?

Comment: It sounds like the output you're expecting is supposed to be the output of some test driver exercising your code, not the output of running your file directly.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to remove the space after "print" to get what you are trying to do, but as @Brack mentions, you will still need to call the function:

```
def one():
    print('Question 1')
```

Console Input:

```
one()
```

Output:

```
'Question 1'
```